R Likert plot with only positive values is not horizontally centred (package likert)
I am creating a Likert plot using the Likert package in R. One variable (used in the repex below) is an ordered factor with only positive responses. The bar is not centered on the y-axis (i.e., top to bottom) but instead appears at the bottom of the plot. I would like to create the plot with the bar centered horizontally on the y-axis.
NB I am referring to centering on the y-axis (i.e., top-bottom), not the x-axis (left-right). I know that the neutral category is centred on the x-axis, with positive values to the right and negative to the left.
The below plot illustrates how the bar is not centrally aligned on the y-axis.

The next plot illustrates how the bar is centrally aligned on the y-axis, when I include 'negative' response levels.

This final plot further illustrates the issue. The blue line indicates the horizontal center line on the y-axis, which the bar sits below, rather than being centered on it. The yellow highlight indicates the corresponding unexpectedly large amount of white space.

# Load likert
library(likert)

# Create a data frame 
ben_DF <- data.frame(Farm = factor(c("Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Large increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Large increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland"),
                                   levels = c("Large decrease in crop farmland", 
                                              "Small decrease in crop farmland", 
                                              "No change in crop farmland", 
                                              "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                              "Large increase in crop farmland"),
                                   ordered = TRUE))

# Plot Likert 
plot(likert(ben_DF)) +
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          legend.direction = "vertical")

This could be related to: R likert graph error when grouping and all responses are negative or positive

When you say it "works when using variables with a mix of positive and negative values", can you give such an example? I thought the whole point of using the likert function was so that you can easily distinguish between positive and negative responses by having them on opposite sides of a center line.

I've edited the post to hopefully clarify the issue, which is that the bar is not aligned on the center of the y-axis. Rather, it sits on the "lower half" of the y-axis. In contrast, a variable with both 'negative' and 'positive' response is plotted correctly (i.e., is aligned with centre of the y-axis).

It only centers the central "neutral" category. Try with ben_DF <- data.frame(Farm = factor(rep(c("a", "d"), c(15, 2)),levels = letters[1:5],ordered = TRUE)) And you'll see that the positive and negative and always strictly to the left or right of centerline. In the example you show, clearly that bar is not centered, there is more data on the right.

Sorry, perhaps I've not explained the problem well enough. I am talking about the y-axis, not the x-axis. I know that the neutral category is centred on the x-axis (with positive values to the right and negative to the left). The issue is with the position of the figure on the y-axis (i.e., when looking up and down). I have added an additional plot, with a horizontal blue line indicating the centre of the y-axis, which the bar should be sitting on (rather than below).

Why use a package that has not been maintained for almost ten years?

Following the suggestion by @jay.sf, the 'solution' was to use a different package (specifically gglikert from ggstats). Provided below for completeness.
# Load packages
library(ggstats)
library(labelled)

# Create a data frame 
ben_DF <- data.frame(Farm = factor(c("Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Large increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Large increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                     "Small increase in crop farmland"),
                                   levels = c("Large decrease in crop farmland", 
                                              "Small decrease in crop farmland", 
                                              "No change in crop farmland", 
                                              "Small increase in crop farmland", 
                                              "Large increase in crop farmland"),
                                   ordered = TRUE))

# Plot Likert 
ben_DF <- tibble(ben_DF)
colnames(ben_DF) <- "q1"
gglikert(ben_DF, variable_labels = c(q1 = "Farm"))  +
    theme(legend.position = "right",
          legend.direction = "vertical")+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-1.1, 1.1), labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))


